# How return pdf in json format in rails api

Tags: json, api, pdf, ruby-on-rails-4, wicked-pdf

I am implementing api using rails 4 and my need is to return pdf in json response as the api I build accepts json format. I am using wicked pdf to generate pdf for this application and web(html requests) part is fine with rendering pdf but I need to return/download pdf when I request api in json format .

Can anyone please help me . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a link in your JSON response to download the PDF.